# How do I route network traffic bound to a defined address range through a specific network interface?

Tags: networking

I'm buildung a cluster like the one depicted below. Each logic node (a [Mixtile Blade 3](https://www.crowdsupply.com/mixtile-limited/mixtile-blade-3)) is attached to a dedicated 4-lane PCIe switch and is equipped with two 2.5 GbE ports each. As the PCIe switch only has 4 ports, I'd like to make my logic nodes talk to each other via the PCIe switch and handle traffic to all other nodes via one of the 2.5 GbE switches. The operating system of all nodes will be the current LTS version of Ubuntu.

[image]

Now: How shall I configure the network stack of the four logic nodes, so that traffic heading to another logic node goes via the PCIe switch, and the remainder of the network traffic (= heading to any node besides the logic nodes) via one of the Ethernet interfaces?

Comment: Does the PCIe-side network have a separate subnet from the rest of the network? Have you tried just using standard rules to achieve this? (i.e: for "_Logic node #1_", `pcie0` has address `10.0.0.1/24`, and it's talking to `10.0.0.2`... while `eth0` is `10.0.1.1/24`... if you tried talking to `10.0.1.2`, the traffic would be expected to go via Ethernet)

Comment: You mean that I should give separate IPs to the respective PCIe network ports of the four logic nodes, right? Of course I could do that, but I could also make up a network interface bond out of PCIe + eth0 + eth1, if this is the "cleaner" way.

Answer (score 1):

If :

- all the PCIe interfaces are in subnet A: `10.0.0.0-255`,
- and everything else is in subnet B: `10.0.1.0-255`,
- **and** the nodes refer to each other by the subnet A IPs (not always the case if using DNS names etc),

then you're good - traffic for subnet A will go out the directly connected interface

---

Otherwise, you can always use single-IP routing table entries, but it's more to maintain since you'll need entries for each other logic node:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.2/32 dev pcie0
ip route add 10.0.0.3/32 dev pcie0
[etc]
```